# Using JSON data retrieved via AJAX in separate function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I've followed some steps from another question which didn't seem to help me. I am trying to retrieve some JSON data, store part of the data into a variable and use that variable in a separate function outside of the AJAX request.

My expected response from the json data is http://localhost:8000/tutorials/retrieve/?page=2 (This response shows if I log the variable inside of the AJAX code) however the actual response I get when I try to log the variable from another function is as follows:

n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp: 1436727171161, jQuery21304066238570958376: true, toElement: div#loadmore.recentTutorials…}

Here is the current code

```
 var recentFirstPage = '';

function retrieveTutorials(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/tutorials/retrieve",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
     **some unrelated parsing code here**
      //Set the variable to what I need
      recentFirstPage = data.next_page_url;
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred processing AJAX request.");
    }
});
}

$('#main-content-wrap').on('click', '.recentTutorials', function(recentFirstPage){

        //Does not return expected result
        console.log(recentFirstPage);  
 });
```

When I click .recentTutorials I expect the console to log the data from JSON however it doesn't. Can someone help clear up my error(s)?

Comment: Where is the code that calls `retrieveTutorials`?

Comment: @TonytheTech This is ran on page load and is also linked to a button. $(document).ready(function(){
 retrieveTutorials();
});

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it doesn't log the data from JSON s that the call is asynchronous. This means that the `function` will execute top to bottom without waiting for the call to finish.

One method that's used is to leverage `deferred` objects which return a `promise` on completion. You can accept an anonymous function to the invoker function so that it's call back is executed within the scope of the click.

Observe:

```
function retrieveTutorials(){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/tutorials/retrieve",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

$('#main-content-wrap').on('click', '.recentTutorials', function(){

     //store our function call as an ajax promise
     var promise = retrieveTutorials();

     //wait for the ajax to return so we can mutate the data
     promise.done(function(data){
         //now our data will be properly
         recentFirstPage = data.next_page_url;
     });

});
```

Comment: Hello, I've received the following error after running your code: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: @Dale Sorry about that - you're right. Call `.done()` instead.

Comment: The same error, only replaced with done now. This also seems to re-run the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in your  click handler is the last and final nail in your coffin. It's always the jquery event and you shouldn't handle it at all.

You do need to call the retrieveTutorials() function within the handler and you need to pass it a callback function that will be executed on success. So your retrieveTutorials() function will look something like this:

```
function retrieveTutorials(success){
     $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "/tutorials/retrieve", 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: success, 
        error: function() { alert("An error occurred processing AJAX request.");
 } }); }
```

And your click handler:

```
$('#main-content-wrap').on('click', '.recentTutorials', function(){
    retrieveTutorials(function(data){
        console.log(data.next_page_url);

    });

 });
```

You can also use all the promise based goodness in the other anwers, but the above would be an idiom you'll see again and again.

Comment: Hi @RobertMoskal, I don't fully understand your answer. Could you add some more detail?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to log the data before the ajax is completed. It`s better to use [deferreds](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) . Try this:

```
function retrieveTutorials(){
  return $.ajax({ // will return deferred object
    type: "GET",
    url: "/tutorials/retrieve",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
     **some unrelated parsing code here**
      //Set the variable to what I need
      recentFirstPage = data.next_page_url;
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred processing AJAX request.");
    }
});
}

$.when( retrieveTutorials() ).done(function ( data ) {
    console.log(recentFirstPage);  
});
```

Comment: This code returns the original blank variable set at the start. I changed the second section to set recentFirstPage = data.next_page_url in the second function ( $.when( retrieveTutorials() ).done(function ( data ) {
    recentFirstPage = data.next_page_url;... ) and it returned the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next_page_url' of undefined